# Generic List and reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'd like to call via reflection the following method, but I have problem to specify the correct signature:

```
 public void executeRule(List<Node> params, SomethingStrangeFound callMeBack) throws IOException
 {
      ...
 }
```

I tried something like this:

```
 Class partypes[] = new Class[2];
 partypes[0] = Class.forName("java.util.List");                 
 partypes[1] = Class.forName("vp.SomethingStrangeFound");

 Method meth = cls.getMethod("executeRule", partypes);
```

It doesn't work because I use "java.util.List" when it must be "List<Node>", but I have no idea how to specify it.

If I just use "java.util.List", I have the following error calling  cls.getMethod("executeRule", partypes):

```
 NoSuchMethodException: vp.RuleWebXmlContextParamFacesPortletRenderStyles.executeRule(java.util.List, vp.SomethingStrangeFound)
```

Any help?

P.S.
At debug time, I see "List<Node>" is resolved with:
               (Ljava/util/List<Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;>;Lit/vp/SomethingStrangeFound;)V

but it doesn't help me.

Comment: At runtime it will be `java.util.List` due to type erasure, so it mustn't be a problem.

Comment: `partypes` array should have length equal to 1, also you can simplify you code to `Class partypes[] = new Class[]{List.class};`

Comment: @Luiggi It cause me a problem because when I call getMethod("executeRule", partypes) I receive an exception: NoSuchMethodException, because types are different.

Comment: @hoaz I had lost a line of code in my post, I had added now :)

Comment: Both Luiggi and Hoaz are right.

Comment: Are you sure `params` is a `List<Node>` and not a `List<Node>[]`? Where does `cls` come from? You could easily debug this by looping over and printing each method in `cls.getDeclaredMethods()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and it worked for me.
You have not provided the definition of cls, but I assume it is something like

```
Class cls = RuleWebXmlContextParamFacesPortletRenderStyles.class;
```

Since you get a NoSuchMethodException, Class.forName already passed successfully, so no typo there (unless you have multiple SomethingStrangeFound classes, which would mean that you got the package wrong).

Because of this the last thing that comes to my mind is that perhaps you compiled RuleWebXmlContextParamFacesPortletRenderStyles before adding the method in question. Clean your code and recompile.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just messed up with packages. Now it seems working. All the guys suggesting to use just List.class or java.util.List were right.

Answer (score 3):

If both parameter classes are available at compile time you can initialize parameter array like this:

```
Class partypes[] = new Class[] { List.class, SomethingStrangeFound.class };
Method meth = cls.getMethod("executeRule", partypes);
```

This will guarantee that you have not mistyped qualified class names.

If this still does not work, check available methods in your class using Class#getMethods() method:

```
for (Method method : cls.getMethods()) {
    System.out.println(method);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With partypes of size 2, getMethod will search for a method called "executeRule" with 2 parameters, one of type "java.util.list" and other of type "vp.SomethingStrangeFound"

But your method has only 1 parameter. You need to add a second parameter of type "vp.SomethingStrangeFound" to your method or set partypes size to 1.

Comment: Sorry, I gave a simplified version of the code deleting the second parameter, since it doesn't give troubles. However, to be more coherent I edited the post again with both the paremeters.

Comment: @DuccioFabbri I tried the code in your post before edit (with only the list as parameter) and worked fine. Maybe the problem is in the "vp.SomethingStrangeFound"?